# How many Space Marine Chapters are lost due to the Tyranid encroachment?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Ultramarines came close to extinction but survived due to the courrage and tenacity of the First Company.

I remember reading a while back that the fleets of Tyranid have devouered some planets that had Space Marine fortress monasteries on them. I taught those were the Silver Skulls and the Howling Gryphones but a Quick Google disproved me.
Is there a list of all the Space Marine chapters lost to Kraken/Leviathan??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [40k wikia](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Space_Marine_Chapters) on Space Marine chapters, the following were completely wiped out or devastated by a tyranid Hive Fleet or tyranids in general :

- [Crimson Castellans](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Crimson_Castellans)
- [Lamenters](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Lamenters)
- [Scythes of the Emperor](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Scythes_of_the_Emperor)
- [Shadow Wolves](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Wolves)
- [Sons of Dorn](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Sons_of_Dorn)
- [Steel Confessors](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Steel_Confessors)

Comment: I'm nitpicking of course, but afaik, the Lamenters have only gone missing. Although they went missing with only 3 companies left, so yeah, they were pretty much done for already. Nevertheless, I doubt GW would such an illustrous chapter get eradicated.

Comment: @Godzillarissa after going over the links again I can see that the Lamenters were _devastated_ by the tyranids. So as you say, they were not eradicated, but I mention in the answer _the following were completely wiped out or devastated..._